# Cannot install xorgxrdp due to dependency issues

Tags: package-management, xorg, xrdp

I am following a video on xRDP from windows RDP and I needed to install xorgxrdp. When I try that I am told there are some dependency issues such as below:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xorgxrdp : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23
            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I found this page very helpful: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390
Specifically, the following steps fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

The page warns that you might lose local keyboard/mouse input if you reboot after the first step; the second step will fix it.