# Unmet dependencies ubuntu 22.04 & amdgpu HIP support

Tags: apt, dependencies, 22.04, amdgpu

I have a ryzen pc with an AMD Radeon Vega card, running ubuntu 22.04LTS, and I'm trying to install the amdgpu-install_22.10.2.50102-1_all driver so that I can use Blender 3.2 and have HIP support. However, I'm having a terrible time, and all my efforts have been for nought.

When I run the command `amdgpu-install -y --opencl=rocr`

I get the following ouput:

```
linux-headers-5.15.0-40-generic is already the newest version (5.15.0-40.43).
linux-headers-5.15.0-40-generic set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.5) but it is not going to be installed
grub-efi-amd64-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-bin (= 2.06-2ubuntu7)
                     Depends: grub-efi-amd64 or
                              grub-pc but it is not going to be installed
init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
libegl1-amdgpu-mesa : Depends: libudev1 but it is not installable or
                            libudev0 but it is not going to be installed
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers : Depends: libudev1 but it is not installable or
                                    libudev0 but it is not going to be installed
 libgbm1-amdgpu : Depends: libudev1 but it is not installable or
                       libudev0 but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx : Depends: libudev1 but it is not installable or
                               libudev0 but it is not going to be installed
 rocm-llvm : Depends: python but it is not installable
         Depends: libstdc++-5-dev but it is not installable or
                  libstdc++-7-dev but it is not installable
         Depends: libgcc-5-dev but it is not installable or
                  libgcc-7-dev but it is not installable
         Recommends: gcc-multilib but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: g++-multilib but it is not going to be installed
 util-linux : PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu : Depends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not 
installable
Depends: xorg-video-abi-24 but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held 
packages.
```

I was under the impression that the driver was supported in Ubuntu 22.04LTS. I am new to Ubuntu so how do I get these installed if they're not installable, or is it all impossible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install xorgxrdp due to dependency issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155964/cannot-install-xorgxrdp-due-to-dependency-issues)

Comment: I've had my own set of dependencies issues with Ubuntu 22.04.  Run `sudo apt update && apt upgrade` first, of course, but try running `sudo depmod`, which will regenerate the kernel module dependency database/list.  Then, re-try your command.  Other factors may be at work but this may eliminate some of them.

Comment: @David No, but thanks

Comment: Synaptic Package Manager tells me I have zero broken and zero upgrage, and zero to remove.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem. Now I fixed.

## check package files

dpkg -L amdgpu-install

## here is key.

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list

## there is an error/typo in these files.

Try changing from `focal` to `jammy`, as in "Jammy Jellyfish".

I installed successfully with below.

amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,opencl --vulkan=amdvlk,pro

Answer (score 11):

Try:

amdgpu-install --usecase=opencl,graphics -y

The issue is that the default "usecase" includes hip, which isn't supported yet for 22.04 due to a python dependency issue. Installing only graphics (mesa) and opencl should be fine.

Answer (score 9):

So, despite AMD releasing an official driver package for Ubuntu 22 they didn't actually make sure the dependencies were compatible. They are aware of this and have promised to fix it, you can follow that in these two issues, [here](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/1730) and [here](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/1713).

Within one of these [issue threads](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/1713#issuecomment-1193332549) is the following workaround:

We are essentially going to download the `rocm-llvm` package, extract it, modify it, compile it again and then install it, fulfilling the dependencies the AMD Drivers need to install.

I didn't encounter the errors with `libegl` and `libgbm1` so they might be related to something else or they may have been fixed by the latest amdgpu-install which I have: version `22.20.50200`.

1. Open a terminal, create a new directory and go into it.
   `mkdir temp` `cd temp`
2. Download the rocm-llvm package `apt download rocm-llvm`. It's 695MB.
3. Extract it `ar x rocm-llvm_14.0.0.22204.50200-65_amd64.deb`
4. Extract control.tar.xz `tar xf control.tar.xz`
5. Open `control` in a text editor `gedit control`
6. Locate the line starting with `Depends` and replace it with this:
   `Depends: python3, libc6, libstdc++6|libstdc++8, libstdc++-5-dev|libstdc++-7-dev|libstdc++-10-dev, libgcc-5-dev|libgcc-7-dev|libgcc-10-dev, rocm-core`
7. Save the file and close the editor.
8. Rebuild control.tar.xz `tar c postinst prerm control | xz -c > control.tar.xz`
9. Rebuild the .deb file `ar rcs rocm-llvm_14.0.0.22204.50200-65_amd64.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz`
10. Install new dependencies `sudo apt-get install libstdc++-10-dev libgcc-10-dev`
11. Install the new .deb file `sudo dpkg -i rocm-llvm_14.0.0.22204.50200-65_amd64.deb`
12. Install dependency for rocm `sudo apt install rocm-core`
13. Download the latest Ubuntu Driver installer `wget https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/22.20/ubuntu/jammy/amdgpu-install_22.20.50200-1_all.deb`
14. Install the latest Ubuntu Driver Installer.
    If it asks if you want to overwrite any sources files, you need to type `Y` so it will do this, if you've upgraded from 20.04 it is asking if you want to replace the old 20.04 sources with the new 22.04 versions.
15. Run the driver installer again:
    `sudo amdgpu-install --opencl=rocr -y`

If at the end of installation it says

```
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.13.11.21.50-1384495/source/dkms.conf does not exist.
WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel
```

Then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure amdgpu-dkms` and it should resolve it.

Answer (score 8):

I also ran into this issue after upgrading a machine to 22.04.1 LTS and using an older RX 580 GPU with kernel version 5.15.0-56.  In case anyone out there is in my situation and comes here, as of this writing (Dec 2022), the following worked for me:

- Use the amdgpu-install version 22.40 from https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/22.40/ubuntu/jammy/amdgpu-install_5.4.50401-1_all.deb
- Install with the command `sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=workstation -y  --opencl=rocr --vulkan=pro --accept-eula --no-32`
- Install the Mesa OpenCL shared library with `sudo apt install -y mesa-opencl-icd`

The `-y` and `--accept-eula` skips the EULA prompt and the `apt` prompt.  `--usecase=workstation`, `--opencl=rocr`, and `--vulkan=pro` install options installs both graphics and OpenCL components, skipping the open-source vulkan.  Finally, the `--no-32` skips installing 32-bit components, which was also giving me issues on some attempts.

`mesa-opencl-icd` is required in order to get the library `libMesaOpenCL.so.1` on my system.  After installing this, I am able to see my GPU with `clinfo -l`:

```bash
$> sudo clinfo -l
Platform #0: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Platform #1: Clover
 `-- Device #0: Radeon RX 580 Series (polaris10, LLVM 13.0.1, DRM 3.49, 5.15.0-56-generic)
Platform #2: Portable Computing Language
 `-- Device #0: pthread-Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
```

Comment: Yours worked for me, thank you. I think I was running into an issue with no-32 in retrospect, because all the packages that wouldn't install were i386 architecture.

Comment: this worked for me for ubuntu 22.04.. Now kdenlive hardware encoding works.

Answer (score 2):

If you browse in here https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/ to the latest drivers the repos are no longer named incorrectly. You'll still get the dependcy error if you dont specify your use cases as others have said. So install the latest one from there (november 22 release at the time of writing this) and then run this you should get a working driver:
amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,opencl --vulkan=amdvlk,pro

Answer (score -1):

I messed around for hours today following errors, found AMD Community page with same error and good answer, that AMD has updated install package, but its not on main page.
https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/cannot-run-amdgpu-install-on-ubuntu-22-04-1/td-p/561053

https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/22.20.5/ubuntu/jammy/amdgpu-install_22.20.50205-1_all.deb

worked for me with:  `amdgpu-install --usecase=opencl,graphics -y`

Mint21 Vanessa & RX570

Comment: This adds nothing to the already existing answers. Plus, Mint is off-topic here.