# Frozen on splash screen - 22.04 + AMD + Gigabyte Motherboard

Tags: drivers, graphics

Recently allowed the update to 22.04, and after getting frustrated with NVidia drivers, switched to a GIGABYTE Radeon RX 6600 on my Gigabyte Z97X-Gaming 7 motherboard. This has not helped resolve my boot issues.

Booting with nomodeset works with the onboard graphics.

I have run amdgpu and followed the advice here [Unmet dependencies ubuntu 22.04 & amdgpu HIP support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417418/unmet-dependencies-ubuntu-22-04-amdgpu-hip-support) to resolve dependencies. I have most recently tried amdgpu-install –usecase=opencl,graphics -y .

Running amdgpu-install appears successful, but ends with states:
WARNING: nomodeset detected in kernel parameters, amdgpu requires KMS

Editing at boot to remove nomodeset, quiet, splash, and $vt_handoff leads to a frozen splash screen on the monitor connected to the graphics card (via DisplayPort). The last journal entry before reboot states that 8ms is spent on flushing the journal. The journal is not overly large.

Leaving $vt_handoff in produces a blank screen on the internal graphics connected monitor.

amdgpu.dc=0 and 1 do not resolve the issue.

In no instance can I switch to a terminal once the display is frozen.

Previous attempts have landed on HSW/BDW HD-audio HDMI/DP requires binding with gfx driver.

A parallel install of 20.04.1 encounters the same issues.

Would someone please recommend next steps?

Comment: When you install proprietary and unsigned drivers then you must either disable Secure Boot in UEFI or use the mokutil tool to sign the drivers. Using the included and open-source `amdgpu` does not require additional steps and, most importantly, it should work! You'd better troubleshoot that instead of installing `amdgpu-pro` . And part of that troubleshooting may include updating UEFI and/or adjusting some settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Disabling secure boot got me further. I could have sworn I had checked that.