# How to install amd gpu drivers ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: amd-graphics

How do you install AMD GPU drivers for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Desktop)? It only installs the archive and not the drivers.

Comment: What is the model of your CPU and graphics card?

Comment: `It only installs the archive and not the drivers.` -- What exactly did you try?

Comment: Your title says you are running Ubuntu Core 22. This is the only version that uses a single digit version. The body says 22.04. Please EDIT the question the clarify the version.

Comment: AMD graphics work with open-source drivers, there's absolutely no need for any user action.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Comment: Archisman, I have a 3500 and RX570 5Gig. I have tried the "installer" package directly from AMD's website and it does not work with the instructions listed, as it is a deb file and not a tar file...... The operating system will open the .deb file in the Ubuntu store and install it. The issue is that it will only install the archives (think that's what it said?) but it will not install the drivers, which is evident by the fact that they will not appear in the 3rd party drivers section of the drivers application and won't appear in terminal at all.

Comment: Also, there is need for user action...... AMD drivers are better, especially in our use case, which will be gaming...... The open source drivers don't have all of the features and resources to help use the GPU to it's full advantage...... Especially while gaming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I suppose you have installed the deb from amd.com, and  looked at https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

However, these instructions do not currently work, it seems. A lot of people around the interwebs have the same problem.

A couple of solutions have been presented, ie [Unmet dependencies ubuntu 22.04 & amdgpu HIP support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417418/unmet-dependencies-ubuntu-22-04-amdgpu-hip-support)

But I myself haven't gotten any proposed solution to work. It seems  we have to wait until amd at a random moment decides to actually fix this....

Comment: Thank you. I'll just wait for the new instructions to come out in the meantime and will try your suggested method. Ill update you all on everything that happens. Once again, thank you so much for the help. This explains a lot.

Comment: worked for me... see my own answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433335/no-hdmi-output-for-wayland-bad-output-or-half-screen-for-x11-22-04-and-asus-ry/1433498#1433498

Comment: AMDGPU just simply doesn't work, has not worked for years (if it ever did...) and they don't care enough about you to provide working drivers because they spend all their time on developing solutions for the only OS that can get a computer virus. I am posting aggressively on this to finally just call them out because I paid over $300 for a GPU to play a single Steam game on Linux, got it working once after days of effort, and 2 days later it all broke with a security software update.

Just RMA your ATI card and get a refurb NVidia because they at least provide drivers.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having to downgrade to Ubuntu 20.04. AMD drivers work fine with that, could not get them to work in 22.04 no matter what I tried.

Comment: That's maybe a half-decade ago. Why would anyone want to spend money for this? AMD claims it works, and even throws in a HWE kernel option, but clearly hasn't done any work to update their soft in forever.

Answer (score 1):

These are the *official guideline* to install proprietary AMD graphic drivers:

- go to https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers and download the correct driver
- launch: *(package name may change)*

`sudo dpkg -i ./amdgpu-install_....deb`

`sudo amdgpu-install -y --usecase=graphics,rocm`

`sudo usermod -a -G render,video $LOGNAME`

- reboot

It takes a lot of time, because it compiles all possible amdgpu modules, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with an amd radeon rx580 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I use the 22.20.50204-1 version of the amd driver with linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic. I noticed this when I tried to fix the system when gui crashed on booting after installing the driver on a newer kernel version.

I chrooted from usb and removed all installed kernel versions as I knew there was trouble with newer kernels with another, a bit older, amd driver. Then I forgot to install the kernel version I had planned to install before i started the amdgpu-install in the chrooted system.

I used it with workstation profile, legacy opengl and vulkan pro and the installer installed the 5.15.0-46 kernel as dependency. All worked fine, modules were compiled and system is running with the new driver. I blocked the installation of newer kernel versions for the moment, but I will test newer ones from time to time ;-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 22.04 LTS [Register kernel-mode driver](https://rocm.docs.amd.com/projects/install-on-linux/en/latest/how-to/native-install/ubuntu.html).

Registering repositories

```
# Make the directory if it doesn't exist yet.
# This location is recommended by the distribution maintainers.
sudo mkdir --parents --mode=0755 /etc/apt/keyrings

# Download the key, convert the signing-key to a full
# keyring required by apt and store in the keyring directory
wget https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/rocm.gpg.key -O - | \
gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/rocm.gpg > /dev/null
```

Add the AMDGPU repository for the driver.

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/rocm.gpg] https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/6.0.2/ubuntu jammy main" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu.list

sudo apt update
```

Install kernel driver

```
sudo apt install amdgpu-dkms
sudo reboot
```

Then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure amdgpu-dkms`

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me -

I installed the `gdebi` package

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Then I went to [and GPU drivers for linux](https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers)

I downloaded the driver for Ubuntu 22.04. It is named `amdgpu-install`

I installed it using -

```
sudo gdebi amdgpu-install
```

Then,

```
sudo apt install amdgpu
```

Comment: Your solution isn't even close to usable. Even on a fresh OS install of 22.04.

Comment: As of at least late 2023, amdgpu-install does not work on any recent version of Ubuntu.  There is a compile error in the dkms build.  Either AMD doesn't care, or they've not checked their build logs in quite a while.