# Ubuntu 22.04 booting into tty only

Tags: boot, drivers, 22.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 machine with a older amd graphics card (details below). As a bit of background it was running on Linux Mint for a year and a half. After some trouble with corrupting the hard drive I switched it to Ubuntu a few months ago.

The last time it booted correctly, 3 or 4 days ago, I think I ran an update in the background while playing some games. Then I shutdown and tried starting it again a couple of days later. Now I can't boot into the ubuntu desktop. It boots into a screen with a blinking cursor and I can get to TTY with Ctrl+Alt+F2. I am also able to SSH into it.

I have done some looking and tried a couple of solutions. I have tried starting Xorg manually using startx, but that didn't work. I have also tried using nomodeset on the grub config to get it to boot and that give me an error. I tried reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop. I also tried to boot under the previous kernel, but seemed to have the same problem. I looked at the xorg logs but only seemed to find the one from the last time I got in it, and the one I tried to start manually. I have had trouble finding anything similar that is on a recent version of Ubuntu. I have continued to try to run any ubuntu updates to see if it is fixed with any patches.

I think this might could be a problem between the kernel and the GPU driver, but that is just a lead from something I read where there could be issues with newer kernels and the amdgpu driver.

I have used various Linux distributions for years, but am not an expert. With that I have reached the end of my knowledge and Googling ability. So any help would be appreciated. I had just gotten this install set up the way I wanted and working pretty well, so I don't really want to reinstall, especially since the os seems to work except for the GUI.

Machine Details:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
Host: B450 AORUS PRO WIFI
Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic
Packages: 2444 (dpkg), 8 (flatpak), 14 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.1.16
Resolution: 2560x1440
Terminal: /dev/pts/0
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X (12) @ 3.600GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590
Memory: 560MiB / 15943MiB

07:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df] (rev e7) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Radeon RX 580 Armor 4G OC [1462:3418]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 111, IOMMU group 15
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
        Memory at fce00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
```

/var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[ 25822.811]
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.3
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 25822.812] Current Operating System: Linux chuck 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64
[ 25822.812] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-58-generic root=UUID=c1bcafb2-ca43-4924-be48-4962bf748b97 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[ 25822.812] xorg-server 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.5 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[ 25822.812] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[ 25822.812]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 25822.812] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 25822.812] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 14 16:43:18 2023
[ 25822.812] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 25822.812] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 25822.812] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 25822.812] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 25822.812] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 25822.812] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 25822.812] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 25822.812] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 25822.812] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 25822.812] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[ 25822.812] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 25822.812] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 25822.812]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 25822.812] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[ 25822.812]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 25822.812] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[ 25822.812]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 25822.812] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[ 25822.812]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 25822.812] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[ 25822.813]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 25822.813] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[ 25822.813] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 25822.813] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 25822.813] (II) Loader magic: 0x557e780b7020
[ 25822.813] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 25822.813]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 25822.813]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[ 25822.813]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[ 25822.813]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 25822.813] (--) using VT number 2

[ 25822.813] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[ 25822.814] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 25822.814] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.0/drm/card0
[ 25822.830] (--) PCI:*(7@0:0:0) 1002:67df:1462:3418 rev 231, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/2097152, 0xfce00000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000e000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[ 25822.830] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 25822.830] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 25822.831] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 25822.831]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.0.0
[ 25822.831]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[ 25822.831] (II) Applying OutputClass "AMDgpu" to /dev/dri/card0
[ 25822.831]    loading driver: amdgpu
[ 25822.831] (==) Matched amdgpu as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 25822.831] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 25822.831] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 25822.831] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[ 25822.831] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[ 25822.831] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 25822.831] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[ 25822.831] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[ 25822.833] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 25822.833]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 22.0.0
[ 25822.833]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 25822.833]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 25822.833] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[ 25822.833] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[ 25822.833] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 25822.833]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 19.1.0
[ 25822.833]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 25822.833]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 25822.841] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 25822.841] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 25822.841] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 25822.841]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.21.1
[ 25822.841]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 25822.841]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 25822.841] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[ 25822.841] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[ 25822.841] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 25822.841]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
[ 25822.841]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 25822.841]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 25822.841] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[ 25822.841] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[ 25822.841] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 25822.841]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
[ 25822.841]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 25822.841]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 25822.841] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
        All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[ 25822.841] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[ 25822.841] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[ 25822.841] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[ 25822.868] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[ 25822.868] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[ 25822.868] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[ 25822.868] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[ 25822.868] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[ 25822.868] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 25822.868]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.0.2
[ 25822.868]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 25822.868] (II) AMDGPU(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[ 25822.868] (==) AMDGPU(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[ 25822.868] (II) AMDGPU(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[ 25822.868] (==) AMDGPU(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 25822.868] (==) AMDGPU(0): RGB weight 888
[ 25822.868] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[ 25822.868] (--) AMDGPU(0): Chipset: "AMD Radeon RX 580 Series" (ChipID = 0x67df)
[ 25822.868] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[ 25822.868] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[ 25822.868] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
[ 25822.869] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[ 25822.869] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[ 25822.869] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[ 25822.889] (EE)
[ 25822.889] (EE) Backtrace:
[ 25822.890] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x139) [0x557e78028719]
[ 25822.890] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__sigaction+0x50) [0x7f2378ae6520]
[ 25822.891] (EE) 2: ? (?+0x0) [0x7ffe44a54138]
[ 25822.891] (EE)
[ 25822.891] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x7ffe44a54138
[ 25822.891] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[ 25822.891] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[ 25822.891] (EE)
[ 25822.891] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[ 25822.891] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 25822.891] (EE)
[ 25822.926] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Worth having a look at the logs to see if any other information is available that you can add to your question: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/viewing-and-monitoring-log-files#1-overview

Comment: Thanks, I pulled the Xorg log file and added it to the question. There is something about a segmentation fault and that the server was aborting. I do remember doing a bit of research on that message earlier in the process, but I didn't have any luck. I don't know enough about how the display stuff works to figure it out from the error alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get back into a GUI. I don't know if this is the best solution, but it got me back to were I can login and evaluate. It also confirms a suspicion I had about it being driver related.

I followed a link on an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1432539/427680) about AMD graphics drivers where you could install them directly from AMD (I am guessing these are possibly the proprietary drivers). I ended up at the [AMD Support Page](https://www.amd.com/en/support) were I was able to pick my graphics card, and then download a .deb package to install. I used scp to copy it over to the affected machine and used dpkg to install it.

After installing the .deb package I ran the `amdgpu-install` script that actually does the install. [amdgpu-install Documentation](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-script.html)

After running that I rebooted the computer and the login came up. So I guess it is working now, and was something to do with the graphics drivers conflicting with something.