# What setup is required to use an AMD graphics card?

Tags: 22.04, amd-graphics

I am currently building a PC with an AMD Radeon 7800XT and planning to install Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Comment: None? It tends to work out of the box. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I've previously used Arch with an nVidia GPU, where I had to install specific drivers for it to work. I wanted to check if there was any additional things I had to install to use an AMD GPU.

Comment: Add a 800 WATT power supply.... Ubuntu plays very well with AMD GPU. I would install AMD proprietary driver, Ubuntu will put a AMD driver on there, then you can use MUON Package Manager to fine tune your proprietary driver.

Comment: @Nishnabe Can you please elaborate on why a additional 800w power supply would be necessary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install amd gpu drivers ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432449/how-to-install-amd-gpu-drivers-ubuntu-22-04-lts)

Comment: @moo Not really, do I need to install the AMDGPU drivers for the graphics card to work?

Comment: @karel I'm not sure if this applies to the 22.04 version

Comment: It applies to 14.04.5 and later and that includes the 22.04 version.

Comment: stumblebee i looked at the specs on your graphics and read that 800 watt power supply is desired. Not for sure about your specifics, but some cards use a lot of power. I have a 650watt supply for a medium grade GPU. When you install Ubuntu, it will install a driver for your AMD, you 'could' use MUON pkg mgr, to upgrade to AMD proprietary, which is a better driver.

Comment: stumblebee, it is even possible that your GPU card has a power jumper on it. MINIMUM Power is 700 watts. Here are the specs... https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-rx-7000-series/amd-radeon-rx-7800-series/amd-radeon-rx-7800-xt