# AMD Rx 7900XTX screen size on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: display-resolution, amd-graphics, amdgpu

i have a dual boot PC with Win10 and Ubuntu 22.04.1, recently switched from RTX 3070 to RX 7900XTX, installed GPU driver from AMD website, but Ubuntu still allows only 1024x768 resolution.
Had the same problem when downloaded official Nvidia drivers for 3070, had to switch back to some initially installed, but this seem to be not applicable with new Radeon GPU.
No idea how to fix that, i'm also a complete linux noob as you might guess. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a few days of struggling with 1024x768 on a 27" screen i finally found a solution here [Unmet dependencies ubuntu 22.04 & amdgpu HIP support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417418/unmet-dependencies-ubuntu-22-04-amdgpu-hip-support)

i ran

`amdgpu-install -y --opencl=rocr`

and then

`amdgpu-install --usecase=opencl,graphics -y`

and after reboot i got my native resolution finally,
cheers!