# Ubuntu doesn't see my integrated GPU

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, gpu-driver, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

I build my new pc based on CPU Ryzen 5 5600g. That CPU has integrated GPU - Radeon Vega 7. I also use Ubuntu 22.04 as my main os.

The problem is simple: Ubuntu doesn't see/use that integrated GPU, i see it on benchmarks and on the system information screen. Instead of an integrated video card, some unfamiliar device "llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1, 256 bits" is displayed in the status panel.

I tried reinstalling my system, tried to download drivers from official cite an other common possible solutions. Nothing helped.

Maybe you can share some wisdom about that problem with me?

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: Are you using Wayland or Xorg?

Comment: Why do you think the iGPU isn't being used? Do you have a dedicated GPU? If you only have the iGPU and you're running a desktop environment, then it's being used. You don't need to manually download or install any drivers for AMD GPUs (dedicated or integrated)

Comment: @Nmath yes, i know, that my measurements not scientific, but first: when i run some games (such as rimworld), that according to the internet, and common sense, must run just perfectly on my system, i get like 7-9 fps. Yes i know, that it is integrated GPU and it cant be good, but this specific IGPU, actually is. And second, and most important: if you google "llvm", you will get something like this: "LLVMpipe is a unique implementation of Mesa OpenGL software that is used when the graphics card or GPU driver is not found by the computer system or is missing from the system. "

Comment: @FedKad no, i think im not. If they doesn't installed by default. Should i install some of that packages?

Comment: More info here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417418/unmet-dependencies-ubuntu-22-04-amdgpu-hip-support