# Ubuntu 22.04 stuck on /dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, x/x files, x/x blocks

Tags: boot, drivers

Noob Linux user here trying to learn software development.

I installed ubuntu on a dual-boot windows machine yesterday and everything was working fine but today I have booted on my computer to find that Ubuntu freezes on this screen when hitting 208203/12181504 files.

I'm using 22.04.06 software (I believe) and my computer is using AMD graphics (7900XTX) with an Intel I5-13600K CPU.

I managed to get into Ubuntu once today after updating Ubuntu using the root console in recovery mode and it seemed to no longer be using my GPU as I couldn't swap from 75hz default resolution to the 4k resolution I usually use.

It leads me to believe that it's something wrong with the graphics card drivers or display drivers. I'm a complete noob with Linux so I've tried some fixes found on this forum but they usually relate to NVIDIA driver issues.

Also the only console I can get into is the recovery mode root one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*When booting into recovery mode and then hitting resume normal boot I am able to get into Ubuntu but it does not recognize my GPU anymore. I've tried installing linux AMD drivers but finding it difficult.

System tells me I am using GNOME version 42.9, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and graphics llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)

**Installed AMD GPU drivers for 22.04.3, typed in a password for MOK but when rebooting and enrolling a key it told me password was incorrect. However, now when I get to the x/x blocks screen it no longer freezes and I can get to the ctl+alt+f2 terminal.

When installing AMD drivers console gave back warning: nomodeset detected in kernel parameters, amdgpu requires KMS.

Comment: Recovery mode default uses nomodeset boot parameter which forces default llvmpipe graphics. If you need MOK key to install proprietary driver, then you have UEFI Secure Boot on. Many turn it off just to avoid the hassle. Can you boot with Intel graphics? Or turn off Secure Boot and install AMD driver? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417418/unmet-dependencies-ubuntu-22-04-amdgpu-hip-support

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by disabling secure boot in BIOS settings.